# Why fillText doesn't show up in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Tried changing the fillStyle color to many different ones, also different positions but nothing. No errors in console either. I already have tileset and sprites drawn on the canvas, does that has anything to do with it? I just need to print out a simple text on every character move on key press.

Here is the code:

```
function move(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    boatPosX += 5;
    view.x -= 5
    moveCount++;
    context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.fillText(theArray[0].question, 0, 0);
    console.log(theArray[0].question);
  }
```

The rest of the code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var view = {x: 0, y: 0};
var questionsArray = [];
var moveCount = 0;
var mapArray = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];

function isPositionWall(ptX, ptY) {
  var gridX = Math.floor(ptX / 36)
  var gridY = Math.floor(ptY / 36)
  if(gridX < 0 || gridX >= mapArray[0].length)
    return true;
  if(gridY < 0 || gridY >= mapArray.length)
    return true;
    return mapArray[gridX][gridY];
}
var theArray = [];
var Question = function(question, answer1, answer2, correctAnswer) {
  this.question = question;
  this.answer1 = answer1;
  this.answer2 = answer2;
  this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;

  this.addToArray = function(){
     theArray.push(this);
 };
  this.addToArray();
}

Question.prototype.checkAnswer = function() {
  return answer1 || answer2 == correctAnswer;
}

var question1 = new Question("Taip ar ne?", "Taip", "Ne", "Taip");
var question2 = new Question("Jo ar ne?", "Ne", "Jo", "Jo");
var question3 = new Question("Aha ar ne?", "Aha", "Ne", "Ne");
var question4 = new Question("Ja ar ne?", "Taip", "Ne", "Taip");
var question5 = new Question("Jojo ar ne?", "Taip", "Ne", "Taip");
var question6 = new Question("Taip ar ne?", "Taip", "Ne", "Taip");
var question7 = new Question("Taip ar ne?", "Taip", "Ne", "Taip");


var StyleSheet = function(image, width, height, x, y) {
  this.image = image;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y
  this.draw = function(image, sx, sy, swidth, sheight, x, y, width, height) {
    context.drawImage(image, sx, sy, swidth, sheight, x, y, width, height);
  };
  this.drawimage = function(image, x, y, width, height) {
    context.drawImage(image, x, y, width, height);
  };
};

/* Initial Sprite Position */


var boatPosX = canvas.height/2 - 50;
var boatPosY = canvas.height/2 - 50;

function render(viewport) {
  context.save();
  context.translate(view.x, view.y);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  var oldPosX = boatPosX;
  var oldPosY = boatPosY;
  for (let i = 0; i < mapArray.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < mapArray[i].length; j++) {
      if (mapArray[i][j] == 0) {
        this.sprite.draw(
          background,
          190,
          230,
          26,
          26,
          i * this.sprite.width,
          j * this.sprite.height,
          this.sprite.width,
          this.sprite.height
        );
      }
      if (mapArray[i][j] == 1) {
        this.sprite.draw(
          background,
          30,
          30,
          26,
          26,
          i * this.sprite.width,
          j * this.sprite.height,
          this.sprite.width,
          this.sprite.height
        );

      }
      if (mapArray[i][j] == 2) {
        this.sprite.draw(
          background,
          200,
          20,
          26,
          26,
          i * this.sprite.width,
          j * this.sprite.height,
          this.sprite.width,
          this.sprite.height
        );
      }
    }
  }
  this.ship.drawimage(boat, boatPosX, boatPosY, 50, 50);
  //console.log(boatPosX + ship.width)
  if(isPositionWall(boatPosX, boatPosY)) {
    boatPosX = oldPosY;
    console.log("collision");
  }

  context.restore();

};

function move(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    boatPosX += 5;
    //canvas.width += 2;
    view.x -= 5
    moveCount++;
    console.log(moveCount);
    console.log("right");
    context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.fillText(theArray[0].question, 0, 0);
    console.log(theArray[0].question);
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    boatPosX -= 5;
    view.x += 5
    moveCount++;
    console.log(moveCount);
    console.log("left");
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    boatPosY -= 5;
    view.Y += 5
    moveCount++;
    console.log(moveCount);
    console.log("up");
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    boatPosY += 5;
    view.Y += 5
    moveCount++;
    console.log(moveCount);
    console.log("down");
  }
}

document.onkeydown = move;

var background = new Image();
background.src = "ground.png";
var sprite = new StyleSheet(background, 36, 36, 16, 16);

var boat = new Image();
boat.src = "ship.png";
var ship = new StyleSheet(boat, 90, 100, 16, 16);
console.log(Math.floor(boatPosX / 36));
console.log(mapArray[Math.floor(boatPosX / 36)]);


render();
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be because you are trying to put the text at 0,0. By default the text will be drawn above the Y position of 0 (so off the top of the canvas which is why you don't see anything). If you made it 0,10 or 0,20 then you will probably see some text.

It is possible to change the text base line like this, so at 0,0 you will see something..

```
context.textBaseline = "top";
```